# How do I solve the trigonometric equation $\sec^3x - 2 \tan^2 x = 2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, roots

A friend asked to me how could she resolve this equation, but I don't know how to resolve it?? Could you help me?. The equation is :

> $\sec^3x - 2 \tan^2 x = 2$

**Note:** She told me that I can use the quadratic equation

Comment: Is the correct equation $\sec^3x−2 \tan^2 x = 2\,$ ?

Comment: Yes @georg, I wrote it wrong, thanks for the comment, I already fix it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or too

$\sec^3x-2\tan^2x=2\\
\frac{1}{\cos^3x}−2 \tan^2 x = 2\\
\frac{1}{\cos^3x}−2 \frac{\sin^2 x}{\cos^2 x} = 2\\
\frac{1}{\cos x}−2 \sin^2 x = 2 \cos^2x\\
\frac{1}{\cos x} = 2 \cos^2x + 2 \sin^2 x = 2(\cos^2x +  \sin^2 x) = 2\\
\cos x = \frac{1}{2}\\
x = \cdots$

Comment: Thank you, I really understood, I'm so grateful, that was the answer I was looking for. :D

Answer (score 6):

Multiplying both sides of
$$\sec^3x-2\tan^2x=2$$
by $\cos^3x$ gives you
$$1-2\sin^2x\cos x=2\cos^3 x$$
$$\iff 1-2(1-\cos^2x)\cos x=2\cos^3x\iff \cos x=1/2.$$
Hence, the answer is $$x=2n\pi\pm \frac{\pi}{3}\ \ (n\in\mathbb Z).$$

Answer (score 5):

I think I have a simpler answer.  It seems the easiest way to get this equation to depend on only one trig function is to convert the tangent to a secant yielding

$$\sec^3x-2(\sec^2x-1)=2$$
$$\sec^3x-2\sec^2x+2=2$$
$$\sec^3x-2\sec^2x=0$$

So we have $\sec x=0$ which is impossible or $\sec x=2$.  If this doesn't look familiar, take the reciprocal of both sides.